# Как вывести данные json

Tags: vue.js

Делаю запрос axios

```
data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
    }
  },
  axios.post('getone', {
    id: 1
  }).then(res => {
    this.posts = res.data
  })
```

Получаю ответ json `{"id":1,"name":"Alex","age":30}`

Как вывести к примеру

```
<p>1</p>
<p>Alexey</p>
<p>30</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил так:

```
<p v-for="post in posts ">{{ post}}</p>
```